# Getting the source code of the custom indicator MESA

Tags: charts, finance

I would like to ask how to get the source code of a custom indicator offered by the `InteractiveTradingChart` function, in particular the MESA indicator (Maximum Entropy Spectrum Analysis) in its two modes "MESA Sine Wave" and "Mesa Phase" in the section "Cycle" of interactive chart indicator.

I would like to see how it was encoded, and how it is calculated on the graph, also to be able to edit it according to my needs.

I attach the screenshot of the indicator in the interactive trading chart and the respective .nb File found in the Wolfram Documentation to which it refers you can download here (I can't find the original link from which I downloaded it so I'm attaching it for simplicity via dropbox) https://www.dropbox.com/s/wt8rppbqtd9j8wi/CustomIndicator.nb?dl=0

[image]

Comment: [Cross-posted in Community.](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2158923)

Comment: You can always inspect definitions (where accessible) with ``GeneralUtilties`PrintDefinitionsLocal``. My guess is this is implemented in like `FinancialIndicator` or something. No idea what MESA does for you or what the appropriate terminology is, though, which makes it hard to know what part of the `DownValues` to search.

Comment: Working off of that hypothesis I found the function that calculates it ``Visualization`Utilities`FinancialUtilitiesDump`FIMESASW``. Now you can use ``GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitionsLocal[Visualization`Utilities`FinancialUtilitiesDump`FIMESASW]`` to see how it's defined. Specifically ``GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitionsLocal[Visualization`Utilities`FinancialUtilitiesDump`computeMesa]`` might be useful

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this is the programming language used by Mathematica, so I don't know how to try to apply this advice.
Hope for further help.
Thank you